# Is there any way to pre-process this kind of data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to load dataset but having problem

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 1079: invalid start byte
```

I already try

```
 DL = pd.read_csv('eg1.csv',encoding = 'UTF-8')
 DL
```

I think there should be some way to solve this error can anybody help me.

I am attaching the dataset file.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QdbLpeanGyybiJ84V-CB6CdTSXe68sivTjnpcxjpsY/edit?usp=sharing

the main problem causing is this data "10mM NH4OAï½ƒ aq. pH7.0 / 2-propanol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following codec package in the read_csv() command:

file = pd.read_csv('data-preprocess.csv',encoding = 'unicode_escape')